# Break a long line but without spaces, with vim

Tags: vim

There is multiple questions closed to this one, but without the same parameters, and I don't find an answer to my problem.

I have a very long long line whitout whitespaces (base64), that I want to break in multiple lines.

Some answers in the site are to use gq, but without whitespaces, it do not work...

Maybe is it another command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this command, replacing `10` with the desired width:

```
:s/.\{10}/&\r/g
```

It substitutes each group of 10 characters (`.\{10}`) with itself (`&`) followed by a newline, (`\r`).

Comment: I'm an idiot. I make substitution every days, every hours, every minutes, every seconds, every ..., and I don't think about it for my problem.
Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:substitute` to place a newline character (`\r`) into the long line after (`\zs` starts the match only there) every N (`\{N}`, with `g` flag) non-whitespace (`\S`; could also simply use `.`) characters:

```
:s/\S\{10}\zs/\r/g
```